# How to print out every possible arrangement of a given array using recursion

Tags: c, recursion

We are given an array of elements `float val[]={+10, -5, +7, -8};` and i want to print out every possible rearrangement of this matrix using recursion

I have kinda done this but in my textbook the only thing i found close to what i want is the **multiplication principle**

This is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct val_s val_t;
struct val_s
{
    float *choices;
};

void multiplication_principle(val_t *val,float *sol,int n,int pos)
{
    if(pos==n)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            printf("%3.0f ",sol[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        sol[pos]=val[pos].choices[i];
        multiplication_principle(val,sol,n,pos+1);
    }

}
int main() {
    val_t *v;
    float *sol;
    float val[]={+10, -5, +7, -8};
    int n=4;
    v=malloc( n*sizeof(val_t));
    if(val==NULL)
    {
        exit(1);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n ; ++i) {
        v[i].choices=malloc(n*sizeof (float ));
        if(v[i].choices==NULL)
        {
            exit(1);
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            v[i].choices[j]=val[j];
        }
    }
    sol=malloc(n* sizeof(float));
    if(sol==NULL)
    {
        exit(1);
    }
    multiplication_principle(v,sol,n,0);

    return 0;
}
```

And these are the results(not all of them cuz i would have to paste here over 50 or so of them but i think you get the idea)

```
 10  10  10  -5
 10  10  10   7
 10  10  10  -8
 10  10  -5  10
 10  10  -5  -5
 10  10  -5   7 
 10  10  -5  -8 
 10  10   7  10 
 10  10   7  -5 
 10  10   7   7 
 10  10   7  -8 
 10  10  -8  10 
 10  10  -8  -5 
 10  10  -8   7 
 10  10  -8  -8 
 10  -5  10  10 
 10  -5  10  -5 
 10  -5  10   7 
 10  -5  10  -8 
 10  -5  -5  10 
 10  -5  -5  -5 
 10  -5  -5   7 
 10  -5  -5  -8 
 10  -5   7  10 
 10  -5   7  -5
 10  -5   7   7 
 10  -5   7  -8
 10  -5  -8  10
 10  -5  -8  -5
 10  -5  -8   7
 10  -5  -8  -8
 10   7  10  10
 10   7  10  -5
 10   7  10   7
 10   7  10  -8 
 10  -8  10  -8
 10  -8  -5  10
 10  -8  -5  -5
 10  -8  -5   7
 10  -8  -5  -8
 10  -8   7  10
 10  -8   7  -5
 10  -8   7   7
 10  -8   7  -8
 10  -8  -8  10
 10   7  -8   7
 10   7  -8  -8
 10  -8  10  10
 10  -8  10  -5
 10  -8  10   7
 10  -8  -8  -5
 10  -8  -8   7
 10  -8  -8  -8
 -5  10  10  10
 -5  10  10  -5 
 -5  10  10   7 
 -5  10  10  -8
 -5  10  -5  10
 -5  10  -5  -5
 -5  10  -5   7
 -5  10  -5  -8
 -5  10   7  10
 -5  10   7  -5
 -5  10   7   7
 -5  10   7  -8
 -5  10  -8  10
 -5  10  -8  -5 
 -5  10  -8   7
 -5  10  -8  -8
 -5  -5  10  10
 -5  -5  10  -5
 -5  -5  10   7
 -5  -5  10  -8
 -5  -5  -5  10
 -5  -5  -5  -5
 -5  -5  -5   7
 -5  -5  -5  -8
 -5  -5   7  10 
 -5  -5   7  -5
 -5  -5   7   7
 -5  -5   7  -8
 -5  -5  -8  10
```

What i want though is to exclude the repetitions. where i only have the elements used one time like for example

```
10  -5   7  -8
-5  -10   7  -8
7  -5   10  -8
```

and so on

Comment: I don’t know C, but in C++ I think you are looking for this: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation

Comment: @Ben Unfortunately i dont have any experience at all with C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never mind i managed to do it (GREIT SUCCESS)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void permutation(float *val,float *sol,float *mark,int n,int pos)
{
    if(pos==n)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            printf("%.0f ",sol[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        if(mark[i]==0)
        {
            mark[i]=1;
            sol[pos]=val[i];
            permutation(val,sol,mark,n,pos+1);
            mark[i]=0;
        }
    }
}
int main() {
    float *sol;
    float *val;
    int n=4;
    float *mark;
    mark = calloc(n, sizeof(float ));
    if(mark==NULL)
    {
        exit(1);
    }
    val = malloc(n* sizeof(float ));
    if(val==NULL)
    {
        exit(1);
    }
    val=(float []){+10, -5, +7, -8};
    
    sol=malloc(n* sizeof(float));
    if(sol==NULL)
    {
        exit(1);
    }

    permutation(val,sol,mark,n,0);
    return 0;
}
```

And the results

```
10 -5 7 -8
10 -5 -8 7
10 7 -5 -8
10 7 -8 -5
10 -8 -5 7
10 -8 7 -5
-5 10 7 -8
-5 10 -8 7
-5 7 10 -8
-5 7 -8 10
-5 -8 10 7
-5 -8 7 10
7 10 -5 -8
7 10 -8 -5
7 -5 10 -8
7 -5 -8 10
7 -8 10 -5
7 -8 -5 10
-8 10 -5 7
-8 10 7 -5
-8 -5 10 7
-8 -5 7 10
-8 7 10 -5
-8 7 -5 10
```

Comment: It's worth noting what the problem was.

Comment: @tadman Well i changed a few things. And the problem was in the thinking around the problem mostly.

Comment: @tadman What i didnt do before was that i would keep using that number untill the end and then switch numbers. So you create an array called mark which you allocate to 0 in the beginning and as you call in numbers you also increase the value from 0 to 1. And check if the value of the ```mark[i]==0``` it means this number is free to use and so you use it and set the ```mark[i]=1``` to denote that you cant use it no more. then you simply reccurr